# How to initialize a struct of integers to zero?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the best way to make sure the following large struct always has its integers initialized to 0?

```
struct Statistics {
    int num_queries;
    int num_respones;
    // ... 97 more counters here
    int num_queries_filtered;
}
```

I would like to avoid having to check each place this struct is initialized to make sure it is value initialized with `Statistics s();` rather than default initialized with `Statistics s;`.

```
Statistics s;     // Default initialized by accident here
s.num_queries++;  // Oh no, this is a bug because it wasn't initialized to zero
Statistics s2{};  // Correctly value initialized
s2.num_queries++; // Successful
```

**Proposal 1** - Use `memset`, but this feels like a hack where we take advantage of the value initialization happening to be equivalent to 0 filling the data structure:

```
struct Statistics {
    Statistics() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this)); }
    // ... counters here
}
```

**Proposal 2** - Use constructor initialization lists, but this is cumbersome and when people add new counters in the future they may forget to zero-initialize them in the constructor:

```
struct Statistics {
    Statistics() : num_queries(0), num_respones(0), /* ... */, num_queries_filtered(0) {}
    // ... counters here
}
```

**Proposal 3** - Force the value initialization to take place as follows:

```
struct StatisticsUnsafe {
    // ... counters here
}

struct Statistics : public StatisticsUnsafe {
    Statistics() : StatisticsUnsafe() {}
}
```

What do you feel is the best approach? Do you have other alternatives?

**EDIT** I want to clarify that in my actual code, each of the counters has a meaningful name, such as "num_queries_received", "num_responses", etc. Which is why I do not opt to use a vector or array of the form "counters[100]"

**EDIT2** Changed the example from `Statistics s2();` to `Statistics s2{};`

Comment: `counterX` is better off as an array. And you can do `int counter[100]{}` to value-initialize the elements.

Comment: Note that `Statistics s2();` does _NOT_ default initialize a `Statistics`, it declared a function that returns a `Statistics`.  You meant `Statistics s2{};` or maybe `auto s2=Statistics();`

Comment: @MooingDuck, I also thought `Statistics s{};` will do the trick, but got downvoted :)

Comment: @vsoftco: I was pointing out a syntax error in code he said was not what he wanted.  If you assume he meant what I wrote, then your answer is _exactly_ what he said he did not want.

Comment: @MooingDuck, thanks, I realized that now, deleted my answer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 In my actual code each counter has a meaningful name, which is why I chose not to use an array. Editing my question to reflect this.
MooingDuck, Thanks for pointing out my syntax error, corrected it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From C++11, you may also do:

```
struct Statistics {
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    // ... more counters here
    int counter100 = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a fairly specific reason to do otherwise, your first choice should probably be a `std::vector`, such as:

```
std::vector<int> Statistics(100);
```

This will zero all the contents automatically. You can address an individual `counter` in the array as something like:

```
++Statistics[40];
```

...which will increment the 41<sup>st</sup> item (the first is `Statistics[0]`).

If the size if really fixed at 100 (or some other number you know at compile time) you might prefer to use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<int, 100> Statistics;
```

This is potentially a little faster and usually uses a (little) less memory, but fixes the size (whereas with an `std::vector` you can use `push_back`, `erase`, etc., to add and remove items).

Given the edited question (the objects really aren't array-like) I'd probably consider something a little different, probably something like this:

```
template <class T>
class inited {
    T val;
public:
    inited(T val=T()) : val(val) {}
    operator T() const { return val; }
    operator=(T const &newval) { val = new_val; }
};

struct Statistics { 
    inited<int> sum;
    inited<int> count;
    inited<double> mean;
};
```

Then an `inited<T>` is always initialized to some value--you can specify a value if you wish, and if you don't specify any, it uses value initialization (which will give zero for arithmetic types, a null pointer for a pointer type, or use the default constructor for types that define one).

Since it defines an `operator T` and an `operator=`, you can still assign to/from elements, just about like usual:

```
Statistics.sum = 100;
Statistics.count = 2;
Statistics.mean = static_cast<double>(Statistics.sum) / Statistics.count;
```

You might prefer to use a single:

```
operator T&() { return val; }
```

Instead though. This supports both reading and writing (as above) but also compound assignment operators (e.g., `+=` and `-=`).

Comment: I think I would have gone with `std::array` but yeah.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Good point--edited.

Comment: In my actual code, each counter has a meaningful name, like "num_queries" or "num_responses" instead of "counter1" or "counter2". So it would be meaningless to have counter[42]. At best, I could define an enum which maps from indexes to enum names, and use that to index into the array. So that's another option, but seems messy just to get the 0 initialization.

Comment: @AffluentOwl, wrote a comment on your main question about using a `Statistics` as a wrapped class inside another `Wrapper` class, and the `Wrapper` will do the initialization. Not super elegant, but allows you to keep your vars names with the price of an extra structure.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm

Comment: @MooingDuck: Interesting, but (IMO) less than ideal--I prefer one that supports value initialization, but also supports initialization with other values when desired.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Agreed, I'm rather surprised it can't do that yet.

Comment: I like that you provide a very safe answer. However, it has quite a bit of overhead associated with it, just for making sure values are zero initialized. For people adding a new counter to the statistics struct, I feel that it is just as much overhead for them to remember to use an `inited<int> counterX;` as it is for them to remember to use C++11 in-class member initializers `int counterX = 0;`. Therefore, I am going to accept Jarod42's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered writing an initializer for each data member?

```
struct Statistics {
  typedef int counter_t;

  counter_t counter1 = 0;
  counter_t counter2 = 0;
  // ... more counters here
  counter_t counter100 = 0;
};
```

Note that if you include such initializers, though, the struct is no longer an *aggregate*, and hence can't be initialized using [*aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) via a braced list. Whether that matters or not for this type is hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

Well you certainly can do something like:

```
struct Statistics {
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    // ... more counters here
    int counter100 = 0;
};
```

This is perfectly valid in c++11. But the question is, do you really need this? Wouldn't it be more convenient to use a vector?

```
struct Statistics {
    std::vector<int> counters = std::vector<int>(100, 0);
};
```

And if vector is not an option, you can do some magic in constructor:

```
struct Statistics {
    int counter1;
    int counter2;
    // ... more counters here
    int counter100;

    Statistics() {
        for (int * i : {&counter1, &counter2, ..., &counter100 }) {
            *i = 0;
        }
    }
};
Statistics s;
s.counter2; // now stores 0 or anything you like.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `C`-like way:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

struct Statistics {
  int counter1;
  int counter2;
  int counter3;
  int counter4;
  // maybe more //
  Statistics() {
    // checks whether Statistics is standard-layout
    // to be sure that memset won't break it
    static_assert(
        std::is_standard_layout<Statistics>(),
        "Someone broke Statistics, can't use memset to zero it.");
    // initializes hole Statistics's memory by zeros
    memset(this, 0, sizeof(Statistics));
  }
};

// Here is a way how to check Statistics
void assert_Statistics() {
  Statistics s;
  int* ptr   = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&s);
  int  count = sizeof(Statistics) / sizeof(int);
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    assert(*(ptr++) == 0);
  }
}

int main()
{
  Statistics s;
  assert_Statistics();
}
```

Comment: Use of `memset` like this is only well-defined if `Statistics` is standard-layout. I would add a `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Statistics>(), "Someone broke Statistics, can't use memset to zero it.");` in the constructor for future-proofing.

Comment: @Casey good idea, I edited :)